# How can I change django 'timeuntil' template tag output format?

Tags: django

If there are 8 days remaining until May 2, then the template tag `timeuntil` outputs `1 week, 1 day`.

I want to change this to output `8 days`.

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please post the relevant parts of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) based on the implementation of djangos `timesince` template filter.

You can find the code to `timesince` in your django instalation in the file `site-packages/django/utils/timesince.py`.

Looking at the implementation, I don't see a way to just configure the functionality of that function.